# Ubuntu 20.04 Samba Share to Windows, Added a Second Drive Its Not Recognized

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, samba, smb

I configured a server/Plex media server on Ubuntu 20.04, and to transfer and download files directly, I set up Samba shares using the following [tutorial](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-configure-samba-server-share-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux), which was working perfectly.

I added an additional hard drive to expand storage to the PC and read multiple ways on how to mount or add it to Samba for it to be accessible; however, none of them have worked, with the two most popular being:

- Mount it to an existing directory that is already shared with Samba: 
   It worked on the Linux machine, however Windows only recognized it as the original drive and not the new one.
- Mount it in a new directory and add a new share within `smb.conf`:

  ```
  [harddrive]
    path = /media/Storage
    writeable = yes
    valid users = %S
  ```

Am I doing something wrong, or is there a different way to do this?

- Original `smb.conf`:

  ```
  [global]
    workgroup = WORKGROUP
    server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    max log size = 1000
    logging = file
    panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
    server role = standalone server
    obey pam restrictions = yes
    unix password sync = yes
    passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
    passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
    pam password change = yes
    map to guest = bad user
    usershare allow guests = yes
  [printers]
    comment = All Printers
    browseable = no
    path = /var/spool/samba
    printable = yes
    guest ok = no
    read only = yes
    create mask = 0700
  [print$]
    comment = Printer Drivers
    path = /var/lib/samba/printers
    browseable = yes
    read only = yes
    guest ok = no
  [homes]
    comment = Home Directories
    browseable = yes
    read only = no
    create mask = 0700
    directory mask = 0700
    valid users = %S
  [public]
    comment = public anonymous access
    path = /var/samba/
    browsable =yes
    create mask = 0660
    directory mask = 0771
    writable = yes
    guest ok = yes
  ```

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question, but your permissions for newly created files within the shares are wrong: `create mask` should be `2`, `4`, or `6` _(`6` is recommended for Windows shares)_, but never `7`, unless all new files created are intended to be executables.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get around the problem by explicitly naming a user in smb.conf under the [harddrive] section as follows:

[harddrive]
path = /media/Storage
writeable = yes
valid users = UserName

Comment: Does the user you name matter?